# How to convert text to an image?

Tags: image, batch-file, recaptcha

I'm trying to make a human verification system for my site, and I need a way to turn text
(e.g. `What's twelve+3?`) into an image (e.g. [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBFpK.png))...
Any idea how to do this on Windows Command Prompt?
(I am using batch-files as CGI scripts)

P.S. A third-party tool is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Google search it looks like ImageMagick will do what you want. They have downloads for Windows, Mac and Linux. Download the windows portable or dll versions, depending on if you want to use the dll only.

Command from their tutorial to do what you want:

```
convert -background white -fill gray 
-pointsize 36 -size 320x 
caption:'This is a very long caption line.' caption.gif
```

You can change up the options to fit what you need. I would imagine you could substitute a variable with the text you need converted, you can use the @ symbol to pipe in a file as the source.

http://www.imagemagick.com

Comment: works, but you got the syntax really wrong. And it doesnt get the font name.

Comment: If you don't mind commenting the correct syntax I will edit to fix it. I took that example from their website. https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption

Comment: Here's what I used: `convert -background  white -fill gray -pointsize 36 -size 320x   caption:"This is a very long caption line." caption.gif`

Comment: Thank you, I wonder if the syntax errors were from pasting from their site or if the example was wrong.